# How to extract substring by not including alternate text using Python regex

Tags: python, regex

I have the following two strings:

```
various_data/hmsc_proximal_distal/BB_152.HPMSC.distal.tss_ext500bp.narrowPeak
various_data/hmsc_proximal_distal/BB_147.HMSC-he.proximal.tss_ext500bp.narrowPeak
```

What I want to do is to capture:

```
BB_152.HPMSC
BB_147.HMSC-he
```

Why this regex failed:

```
.*\/([A-Z\_0-9\.\-a-z]+)\.[proximal|distal]
```

by giving;

```
BB_152.HPMSC.distal
BB_147.HMSC-he.proximal
```

What's the right way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The regex should be

```
.*\/([A-Z\_0-9\.\-a-z]+)\.(?:proximal|distal)
```

`[]` is a set of characters for one position, you have to use round brackets.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `(?=...` to form a lookahead group

> `(?=...)`
>   Matches if `...` matches next, but doesn’t consume any of the
>   string. This is called a lookahead assertion. For example, `Isaac (?=Asimov)` will match `'Isaac '` only if it’s followed by `'Asimov'`.

```
import re
s = '''
various_data/hmsc_proximal_distal/BB_152.HPMSC.distal.tss_ext500bp.narrowPeak
various_data/hmsc_proximal_distal/BB_147.HMSC-he.proximal.tss_ext500bp.narrowPeak
'''

re.findall(r"([^/]*)\.(?=proximal|distal)", s)
```

yields

```
['BB_152.HPMSC', 'BB_147.HMSC-he']
```

Answer (score 1):

The solution using `re.findall()` function:

```
import re

s = '''
various_data/hmsc_proximal_distal/BB_152.HPMSC.distal.tss_ext500bp.narrowPeak
various_data/hmsc_proximal_distal/BB_147.HMSC-he.proximal.tss_ext500bp.narrowPeak
'''
result = re.findall(r'[A-Z]{2}_\d+\.[a-zA-Z-]+(?=\.proximal|\.distal)', s)

print(result)
```

The output:

```
['BB_152.HPMSC', 'BB_147.HMSC-he']
```

---

- `(?=\.proximal|\.distal)` - lookahead positive assertion, ensures that crucial sequence is followed by either `.proximal` or `.distal`